# Eclipse RCP Application: Problems View, add ellipsis to the text

Tags: eclipse, tree, swt, rcp

We have applied new css styles to our rcp application, for Problmes view, lines are hidden in the following way to remove the tabular format.
`((Tree) control).setLinesVisible(false);`

Now the Problems view is missing the ellipsis for text longer than the column. The padding is also missing at the start of the text in each column, which we were able to fix.

I want to take the approach to append ellipsis(...) to the each `TreeItem` text when the Errors\Warnings `Tree` is expanded in Problems view. I am able to determine the number of columns in the `Tree` and width of each column, since column width will be used to calculate the visible extent of the text.

```
for (TreeItem item : treeItems) {
        String itemText = item.getText();
        if ((itemText != null) && (itemText.length() > width)) {
            itemText = itemText.substring(0, width - ELLIPSIS.length()) + ELLIPSIS;
            item.setText(itemText);
            displayTreeItemChildren(width, item.getItems());
        }
    }
```

Issues I am facing,

1. Not able to retrieve the TreeItem column wise, so that I could apply the substring operation as per the column width
2. Tried with a dummy width, the original TreeItem gets modified in the Tree `treeItem.setText(<modified text>)`, but we would want to retain the original value, and display the modified value. Since column width can be modified by the user.

Comment: Trees using column label providers based on `OwnerDrawLabelProvider` (or one of its many subclasses) get the column width in the erase/measure/paint events. I'm not sure if anything else can get the widths. Also if the view is using a variable width font just testing the number of characters in the string is a poor way of deciding if ellipsis are needed

Comment: If you are asking about the existing Problems view - `org.eclipse.ui.internal.views.markers.ProblemsView` that is an internal class subject to change at any time.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks for the input. Let me check the OwnerDrawLabelProvider implementation.

For your second comment. Yes, I am talking about 
`org.eclipse.ui.internal.views.markers.ProblemsView` only.

Comment: @greg-449 I could see that with the new styling the label provider is missing for the Tree in Problems View. It looks like the Label Provider for Problems view is org.eclipse.ui.internal.views.markers.MarkerColumnLabelProvider.

Comment: If you have replaced the label provider it is up to you to reproduce everything the normal providers do.